# Cropping is done to the left side of image

Tags: php, thumbnails, gd, crop, image-uploading

I am using code for cropping

```
$filename = "thimg.jpg";

// Get dimensions of the coriginal image
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

// Resample the image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor('759', '599');
$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $width/8, $height/8, '759', '599');
imagejpeg($canvas, $filename.'_cropped.jpg', 100);
chmod($filename.'_cropped.jpg', 0644);
unlink($filename);
```

But it is cropped in the left side of image not in the middle.

please provide suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `$width/8` and `$height/8` aren't correct for a centred crop.

You need to calculate:

> (original_width ÷ 2) − (target_width ÷ 2)

and:

> (original_height ÷ 2) − (target_height ÷ 2)

In your specific case that would look like:

```
imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, ($width/2)-(759/2), ($height/2)-(599/2), 759, 599);
```

Note also that you should pass your size values as integer `(759, 599)`, not string `('759', '599')`.

Comment: wow...that exactly what i wanted. just a last request. how can get png and gif, what should i change for png and gif image.

Comment: [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) and [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) to read the images; [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) and [`imagegif`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) to output the images. [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) is an invaluable resource.